# Removing image from server

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to remove the records from the database as well as the uploaded image for that record from the server.I have this function in controller.

```
public function delete(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $id=$request->get('id');
            if($id)
            {
                $delete=Category::where('id',$id)->first();
                $delete->delete();
                $imgfile='C:\xampp\htdocs\larapro\public\newuploads\<?php echo $delete->image;?>';
                unlink($imgfile);
                echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
            }
        }
        echo json_encode(FALSE);die;
    }
```

> unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\larapro\public\newuploads\<?php echo
>   $delete->image;?>): Result too large

if i use

```
$imgfile="C:\xampp\htdocs\larapro\public\newuploads\{$delete->image}";
```

it displays:

> unlink(C: mpp\htdocs\larapro\public\ ewuploads{1470667358.png}):
>   Invalid argument

and i am just wondering why x and n in the link are missing.

Comment: So what's your problem here exactly?

Comment: image is not removed. shows result too large.@PeterPan666

Comment: Why do you have a `<?php ... ?>` block within your PHP function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use slash (/) instead of backslash () in this case:

```
$imgfile="C:/xampp/htdocs/larapro/public/newuploads/{$delete->image}";
```

Or escape the escape character like,

```
$imgfile="C:\\xampp\htdocs\larapro\public\newuploads\{$delete->image}";
```

and the words x and n are missing because \x and \n are escape and new line character respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function delete(Request $request)
        {
            if($request->ajax())
            {
                $id=$request->get('id');
                if($id)
                {
                    $delete=Category::where('id',$id)->first();

                    $imgfile="C:\xampp\htdocs\larapro\public\newuploads\$delete->image";
                    //perform the delete after using the image/filename
                    $delete->delete();

                    unlink($imgfile);
                    echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
                }
            }
            echo json_encode(FALSE);die;
        }
```

Can you substitute your single quotes for doubles and then use the contents of the delete variable?

Comment: You should use curly braces around `{$delete->image}`